# xpath for importxml in google sheet or importing by GAS

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

what is the xpath for importing table on the page:
https://codal.ir/Reports/Decision.aspx?LetterSerial=edVsdLrjCqoJOnLY0QVskw%3D%3D&rt=2&let=8&ct=0&ft=-1

Is it possible by GAS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the table of the URL of `https://codal.ir/Reports/Decision.aspx?LetterSerial=edVsdLrjCqoJOnLY0QVskw%3D%3D&rt=2&let=8&ct=0&ft=-1`.
- You want to achieve this using IMPORTXML and/or Google Apps Script.

I think that in this case, how about using `IMPORTHTML` as follows?

#### Sample using formula:

```
=IMPORTHTML(A1,"table",1)
```

- In this case, the URL of `https://codal.ir/Reports/Decision.aspx?LetterSerial=edVsdLrjCqoJOnLY0QVskw%3D%3D&rt=2&let=8&ct=0&ft=-1` is put in the cell "A1".

Result:

[image]

#### Sample using Google Apps Script:

When Google Apps Script is used, the following script can be also used. [**When you use this script, please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And, please run the function of `myFunction` with the script editor. Because in this case, Sheets API is used for parsing the HTML table. Unfortunately, this cannot be directly used with the custom function. When this function is run, the value is put to the active sheet.

```
function myFunction() {
  const url = "https://codal.ir/Reports/Decision.aspx?LetterSerial=edVsdLrjCqoJOnLY0QVskw%3D%3D&rt=2&let=8&ct=0&ft=-1";
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
  if (res.getResponseCode() != 200) throw new Error(res.getContentText());
  const table = res.getContentText().match(/<table[\s\S\w]+<\/table>/);
  if (table) {
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
    const resource = {requests: [{pasteData: {html: true, data: table[0], coordinate: {sheetId: sheet.getSheetId()}}}]};
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, spreadsheet.getId());
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- When I tested above formula, I have the experience that there is the case that an error of `Could not fetch url` occurs. So please be careful this. At that time, please try to put the formula again. By this, I could obtain the values. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the detail reason of this.

#### References:

- [IMPORTHTML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339)
- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)